# Integration of complex $(p,q)$-form

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

In complex geometry, we have $(p,q)$form $\in$ $\wedge^{p,q}T^*X$, I wonder how to define their integration on submanifold, or top-form on all manifold. For instance, in the Riemann surface book I read, the author let me calculate an integration:

> Prove $(1,1)$-form $\omega=\frac{i}{2\pi}(1+|z|^2)^{-2}dz\wedge d\bar{z}$ could be extend as a smooth $(1,1)$-form on Riemann sphere $S$, and $\int_S\omega=1$.

In fact, I have no idea on all parts of this question, but the crucial problem is the author even do not wrote how to integral a complex differential form on a complex manifold. I wonder how to calculate it.

Comment: It's just the integration of 2 form on S. And your (1, 1) form is actually real, when expressed in (x, y) coordinates.

Comment: What if the (1,1)-form is not real?  I do not know if what you said is complex 2-form, in fact, I do not know how to calculate the integration of a complex form, either.

Comment: Then write your form as $\alpha + i \beta$, where $\alpha, \beta$ are real and $\int (\alpha + i \beta) : = \int \alpha + i \int \beta$.

Comment: @Arctic Char How to deal with $dz \wedge d\bar(z)$, we change it by $dx\wedge dy $ and then do as you did?

Comment: Yes. But the form you have here is real, so $\beta = 0$.

Comment: @Arctic Char Thank you so much. It is very clear. I think it is not a difficult thing, but I do not understand why all complex geo. books do not mention about it.

Comment: Something to understand: If you’re integrating over a $k$-dimensional complex submanifold of $X$, you need to be integrating a $(k,k)$-form.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Thanks a lot, only in this way, it can be changed to $\sum dx_i  \wedge dy_i$, right?